# Getting thumb buttons working | Zowie ec2-b

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, mouse

I'm using `steam` to play `CS:GO` on `Arch Linux`. So far everything works but mouse thumb buttons. I tried to map them in game, then I realized game does not identify those keys at all. I went through Thumb Buttons - forward and back but I think the issue here is `evdev` is not identifying thumb buttons events as buttons. (I'm using `Arch Linux` + `bspwm` + `sxhkd` setup)

#### `xev` output for forward thumb button

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 4046616, (2,420), root:(974,442),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 4046777, (2,420), root:(974,442),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967270 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

#### `xev` output for back thumb button

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 3944070, (7,455), root:(979,477),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 3944181, (7,455), root:(979,477),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967270 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

#### I tried following configurations to `xorg` too.

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier      "Evdev Mouse"
  Driver          "evdev"
  Option          "Name" "Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse"
  Option          "evBits"  "+1-2"
  Option          "keyBits" "~272-287"
  Option          "relBits" "~0-2 ~6 ~8"
  Option          "Pass"    "3"
  Option          "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier     "Default Layout"
  InputDevice    "Evdev Mouse" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

#### I tried killing `sxhkd`

According to solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766775/ubuntu-doesnt-give-the-correct-keycodes-for-some-media-keys) question, keys could be grabbed globally. only potential application would be `sxhkd` so I killed the process and tried thumb buttons on `xev` window but it gave the same results mentioned above.

How do I get thumb buttons working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot that I was running `imwheel` in the background to increase the scroll wheel speed. Mouse buttons are captured globally by `imwheel` but never came out. I could restrict `imwheel` to capture button 4 & 5 as in the answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421645/imwheel-destroys-back-forth-navigation-buttons-from-my-mouse)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so writing this as answer. I'd suggest to check with another common mouse using some known configurations for them, as shown in the following link:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_buttons

For example they indicate there that thumb buttons in most Logitech MX mice resolve to 8 and 9. Once everything works with that other common mouse, troubleshooting with the Zowie might be clearer and easier.